# flowplayer control and video invisible

Tags: video, streaming, flowplayer

On my page, I've loaded flowplayer 3.2.7 and it works everywhere except IE9. On IE9, the video file loads and the audio plays. But the player is invisible as well as the video. BUT, I can mouse over where the controls are and click them. The controls work. I'm not getting any error messages on the developer tools in IE 9.

The video file is large (230MB) but it is playing the audio. The file is a F4V file encoded with Adobe Media Encoder.

I've tried messing with the width/height of the player and embed tags to see if that makes a difference. I've tried everything I can think of.

I'd appreciate some ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code you use to embed Flowplayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it's apparently just my stupid computer because I haven't been able to duplicate it on any other computer.